# LINQ to XML select all values from a list of objects where child and grandchild condition

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have XML like the following

```
                   <trade>
                        <currentBalance>000000100</currentBalance>
                        <account>
                            <type>US</type>
                        </account>
                        <remark>
                            <code>CBG</code>
                            <type>somestring3</type>
                        </remark>
                    </trade>
                     <trade>
                        <currentBalance>000000200</currentBalance>
                        <remark>
                            <code>CBG</code>
                            <type>somestring2</type>
                        </remark>
                        <account>
                            <type>CA</type>
                        </account>
                    </trade>
                     <trade>
                        <currentBalance>000000300</currentBalance>
                        <remark>
                            <code>CBG</code>
                            <type>somestring1</type>
                        </remark>
                        <account>
                            <type>US</type>
                        </account>
                    </trade>
```

I would like to select all of the current balances where the account type is "US" i ran into problems initially because there are two "type" tags, but i was able to get close to getting the correct query by doing the following

```
query = document.Descendants().Where(q => q.Name.LocalName == "trade")
                                            .Descendants().Where(r => r.Name.LocalName == "account")
                                            .Descendants().Where(s => s.Name.LocalName == "type")
                                            .Where(t => t.Value == "US").Select(q => q.Parent.Parent).ToList();
```

This now gives me a list of the two out of 3 trades that i have targeted, but how do i go about actually just getting something to return 000000100, 000000300

Answer (score 0):

I added a root element, so that the XML could be parsed as an XDocument.

```
string xml = @"<root><trade>
                        <currentBalance>000000100</currentBalance>
                        <account>
                            <type>US</type>
                        </account>
                        <remark>
                            <code>CBG</code>
                            <type>somestring3</type>
                        </remark>
                    </trade>
                     <trade>
                        <currentBalance>000000200</currentBalance>
                        <remark>
                            <code>CBG</code>
                            <type>somestring2</type>
                        </remark>
                        <account>
                            <type>CA</type>
                        </account>
                    </trade>
                     <trade>
                        <currentBalance>000000300</currentBalance>
                        <remark>
                            <code>CBG</code>
                            <type>somestring1</type>
                        </remark>
                        <account>
                            <type>US</type>
                        </account>
                    </trade></root>";
```

Then you filter explicitly on the type tag within the trade/account elements and select those accountBalance values.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);            
          var balances = doc.Root.Elements("trade")
                                  .Where(x =>    
                                             x.Element("account")
                                              .Element("type")
                                              .Value == "US"
                                         )
                                         .Select(x => x.Element("currentBalance").Value);
```